# How to prevent infinite re-rendering with useEffect() in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have an app that checks the user id on startup and loads the list of todo items based on the user logged in. I have the useEffect change only when `data` changes, but I have `setData` in the body of useEffect() meaning `data` changes and it re-runs infinitum.

However if I change `[data]` to `[]` in the second parameter, then it renders once BUT I have to refresh the page everytime I add a todo item for it to render rather than it render automatically. How can I have it render automatically without looping infinitely?

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    UserService.getUserById(localStorage.getItem("userId")).then(res => {
        if (res.data !== null) {
            setData(res.data.todos)
        }
    })
}, [data])
```

Comment: Need to show more code.

Comment: @Jakkie Chan to avoid infinity loop you can check previous data (like count) and then you can setData

Comment: @buzatto no, I'm not passing in and comparing any objects

Comment: Why is `data` in the dependency array? It doesn't appear to be a dependency of the effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a condition in the call back function that checks if a certain condition is met, e.g. if data is empty. If it is empty, then fetch data, otherwise do nothing. This will prevent the infinite loop from happening.

```js
const getData =  useEffect(()=>{
  const fetchData = () => {
    UserService.getUserById(localStorage.getItem("userId"))
     .then(res => {
        if (res.data !== null) {
         setData(res.data.todos)
        }
      })
     .catch(error => {
        // do something with error
      })
  }
  
  if (data.length === 0) 
    fetchData()

},[data]);
```

Alternatively, you use an empty dependency array so that the callback function in the useEffect is called once.

Comment: that is equivalent to using `[]` in the second param, it only renders on refresh and not automatically

Comment: where else are you calling `setData` to update it? If you are not calling setData elsewhere in your code then the component will not "automatically" re-render.

Comment: If that's the only place you're calling it then `data` is never updated and therefore your component will never re-render since the component's state variables never change. How are you adding the todo item?

Answer (score 0):

`useCallback` Hook can be used with slight modifications in your code.

You will need to import useCallback from "react" first.

```
import {useCallback} from "react";
```

And then use this `useCallback` around our `getData` function. (*Have modified the answer a bit*)

```
const getData =  useCallback(()=>{
    UserService.getUserById(localStorage.getItem("userId")).then(res => {
        if (res.data !== null) {
            setData(res.data.todos)
        }
    })
},[data]);


useEffect(() => {
   getData();
}, [data])
```

This React Hook will make sure that the `getData()` function is only created when the second argument `data` changes.

Comment: I just tried that, but it still renders it infinitum

Comment: Hmm, I see. You have mentioned in your question that `I have to refresh the page everytime I add a todo item for it to render rather than it render automatically. `. I think that's where we need to improve our code. This is where you actually need to put a handler Function whenever you are may be clicking on add item `button` . If you can show me your code via codesandbox I would like to have a look and see where the problem actually is :-) Also for a time being instead of using `localStorage`, you may simply store all the data in a array of objects for demo purpose :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your code `UserService.getUserById(localStorage.getItem("userId"))` return a **promise** and it get data one time so you just have to call `getUserById` one time at the time of load by using `[]` and if you want to call it again make a function and use it wherever on refresh function or on adding todos item or update or delete function. Otherwise you have to use **observable** or useCallBack hook

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the reset param to prevent loop. once callback trigger reset value false. so that execution not running again until reset the value

**[Codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-silence-c29xj)**

```
  export default function App() {
  let i = 1;
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [reset, setReset] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (reset) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        //callback
        setReset(false);
        setData(Math.random());
      }, 1000);
    }
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{data}</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setReset(true);
          setData("");
        }}
      >
        Click this and see the data render again. i just reset the data to empty
      </button>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a condition to stop the loop by setting a condition to stop it. You can check if a certain value is set or check if there are any values sent at all.