# Why does the useEffect hook run every time I search in the input field and how to prevent unnecessary re-renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why `useEffect` in below code run every time I search in below input?

```js
import SearchInput from './searchInput'

const Sidebar = () => {
  const { list } = useList()
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState<string>('')

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('list :>> ', list)
  }, [list])

  return (
    <SearchInput searchValue={searchValue} setSearchValue={setSearchValue} />
  )
}

export default React.memo(Sidebar)
```

`useList` hook:

```
export default function useList() {
  let { data } = useQuery(GET_LIST)
  const list = _.cloneDeep(data)?.menuTree?.filter((i) => i.parentId === null) || []

  const otherMenus = data?.menuTree || []

  return { list, otherMenus }
}
```

`SearchInput` component:

```js
const SearchInput = ({ searchValue, setSearchValue }) => {
  return (
    <div>
        <Input
          value={searchValue}
          onChange={(e) => setSearchValue(e.target.value)}
        />
    </div>
  )
}

export default React.memo(SearchInput)
```

I believe every time DOM rerenders, `useList` hook runs again, I tried memoizing the component and data returned from `useQuery`, nothing helped. how do I prevent this from
happening?

Comment: At the end of the `useEffect` you have `[list]`. This is called a dependency array and is used to determine when the `useEffect` should trigger, all values in the array will under go a reference comparison against their previous values each render and if any of them have changed trigger the `useEffect`. `useList` is setting list to `_.cloneDeep(data)` each render which is generating a new reference. Each time you call `setSearchValue` you will trigger a rerender. TLDR: `setSerachValue` causes rerender -> `useList` creates a new `list` reference ->  `useEffect` triggered.

Comment: If `data` is memoized you should be able to memoize both `otherMenus` and `list` using `[data]` as the dependency array, ensuring they only update whenever `data` does. This should stop the `useEffect` retriggering more often than expected. If this is not the case we do not have enough information to help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent infinite re-rendering with useEffect() in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65856539/how-to-prevent-infinite-re-rendering-with-useeffect-in-react)

Comment: @JacobSmit I understand the concept, but any idea how do I prevent it. I removed cloneDeep as well, but it didn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function Components are different to Class Components.

In Class Components the aim is to keep the number of rerenders to a minimum as the component does not have the fine grain control over memoization that is provided with Function Components and hooks.

That's not to say that Function Components should not care about rerenders, but you should not be afraid of rerenders. Using correct state and memoization management in most cases a rerender should be indiscernible to the user.

**useList**

```
export default function useList() {
  // useQuery Assumptions:
  //     - internally makes proper use of memoization or
  //       external cache / storage to ensure heavier
  //       calculations are only run when needed.
  //     - data will remain the same reference each render 
  //       unless data has changed.
  let { data } = useQuery(GET_LIST);

  // only recalculate return when data from useQuery
  // has changed reference.
  return useMemo(() => {
    return {
      list: _.cloneDeep(data)?.menuTree?.filter((i) => i.parentId === null) || [],
      otherMenus: data?.menuTree || []
    };
  }, [data]);
}
```

**Sidebar**

```
import SearchInput from './searchInput'

const Sidebar = () => {
  // list should now be only be receiving a new reference whenever
  // data from useQuery receives a new reference.
  const { list } = useList();

  // state value and setter used to store search term.
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState<string>('');

  // useEffect will run on component mount and whenever
  // the list value from useList receives a new reference
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('list :>> ', list)
  }, [list]);

  // render out search input.
  return (
    <SearchInput searchValue={searchValue} setSearchValue={setSearchValue} />
  )
}

// Most of the time React.memo is the incorrect tool to use, 
// heavy calculations should be handled with memoization
// hooks such as useMemo, useCallback, etc.
export default Sidebar
```

**SearchInput**

```
const SearchInput = ({ searchValue, setSearchValue }) => {
  // Render controlled search input.
  return (
    <div>
        <Input
          value={searchValue}
          onChange={(e) => setSearchValue(e.target.value)}
        />
    </div>
  )
}

// Most of the time React.memo is the incorrect tool to use, 
// heavy calculations should be handled with memoization
// hooks such as useMemo, useCallback, etc.
export default SearchInput
```

Anytime that `SearchInput` inside of `Sidebar` calls its `setSearchValue` prop a rerender of the `Sidebar` component will be triggered due to an update of its state value `searchValue`.

This in turn will rerun the `useList` and `useQuery` hooks, but if my `useQuery` assumptions are correct this should be either insignificant or required:

- Insignificant: `data` from `useQuery` has not changed since the last render and no heavy calculations will be run within `useQuery`, as no new reference was given to `data` the `useMemo` with dependency array `[data]` will not be recalculated, avoiding the heavy `cloneDeep` function.
- Required: `data` from `useQuery` has received a new reference signifying a change in the value stored within and possible recalculation of heavy memoized values. This means that the `useMemo` with dependency array `[data]` will be recalculated running the heavy `cloneDeep` function. This would be necessary to ensure the user is seeing the most relevant data.

**Alternative Option**

If the `list` value will have no interaction with the `searchValue` value you could create a wrapping component to handle the search logic / ui of the `Sidebar` (lets call this `SidebarSearch`).

**Sidebar**

```
import SidebarSearch from './sidebarSearch'

const Sidebar = () => {
  
  const { list } = useList();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('list :>> ', list)
  }, [list]);

  // render out search input.
  return (
    <SidebarSearch />
  )
}

export default Sidebar
```

**SidebarSearch**

```
import SearchInput from './searchInput'

const SidebarSearch = () => {
  // state value and setter used to store search term.
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState<string>('');

  // render out search input.
  return (
    <SearchInput searchValue={searchValue} setSearchValue={setSearchValue} />
  )
}

export default SidebarSearch
```

This would mean that whenever `SearchInput` calls the `setSearchValue` prop it would trigger a rerender starting from `SidebarSearch` avoiding `useList` being rerun.